# Details about the detection part of AWS Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'm doing some investigations about AWS Rekognition. There are two issues I need to know but didn't get the answers.

1) how to get the category list of the object detection part.

2) how long does it take to process an image to get object labels in it without considering the data transmission time.

Is there anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
$ time aws rekognition detect-labels \
--image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"my-bucket","Name":"fluffy.jpg"}}' \
--region us-east-1
{
    "Labels": [
        {
            "Confidence": 99.2266845703125, 
            "Name": "Plant"
        }, 
        {
            "Confidence": 99.2266845703125, 
            "Name": "Potted Plant"
        }, 
        {
            "Confidence": 92.96235656738281, 
            "Name": "Animal"
        }, 
        {
            "Confidence": 92.96235656738281, 
            "Name": "Bunny"
        }, 
        {
            "Confidence": 92.96235656738281, 
            "Name": "Mammal"
        }, 
        {
            "Confidence": 92.96235656738281, 
            "Name": "Rabbit"
        }, 
        {
            "Confidence": 92.96235656738281, 
            "Name": "Rodent"
        }
    ]
}

real    0m1.646s
user    0m0.264s
sys 0m0.036s
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, i'm making comparisons on AWS Rekognition and Azure Computer Vision API. But for now, both of the two products are not available to us. Is there a way to compare their processing time under the same image size (4032 x 3024 for example)?

Comment: I suggest you sign-up for an AWS account. Rekognition is $1 for the first million images and there is [5GB of free storage in Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/free/). It'll probably be one of the best $1 you spend! :)

Comment: I will discuss this with my colleagues. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein You may not be able to get the time comparison across both the platforms. Instead you should be focusing on the accuracy of both the platforms and the capabilities each of them offers for comparison. This will help you to judge your selection of platform for image processing.